# BeagleBone Black Ubuntu 14.04.1 TL-WN722n Set Mode fail

Tags: ubuntu, wireless

I am trying to set the mode wireless adapter to monitor following the commands:

`ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
ifconfig wlan0 up`

But when I try to set monitor mode, I fail

`Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.`

And if I try `iwconfig`, it shows

`wlan0     no wireless extensions.`

Could anyone help me fix this problem?
The platform is based on Ubuntu 14.04.1 on BeagleBone Black.
But when I tested on BeagleBoard_xM, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

After hours' search, I foud the following solution:

`nano /etc/rcn-ee.conf
        third_party_modules=enable
wget http://rcn-ee.net/deb/trusty-armhf/v3.8.13-bone56/install-me.sh
sudo /bin/bash install-me.sh
reboot`

reference: http://inspire.logicsupply.com/2014/08/beaglebone-wifi-installation_5.html

Answer (score 0):

Click on the below link to the tool "XEye-tp" I designed on my github profile, you only need to run the tool then your tp-link usb will be set to monitor in few minutes.

XEye-tp: https://github.com/Engmostafa26/XEye-tp